# Count number of occurences for every column in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with an unknown amount of columns (it can change frequently) and I need to count the number of observations for a given ID and year for every column and create a costum "n" column for each column of my dataframe telling me how many observations were made for that specific column.

I have tried:

```
library(dplyr)
count <- tally(group_by(final_database,ID,Year))
```

But that will count unique combinations of ID + Year. While I need to know how many times over the years my ID was observed for each characteristic. Example:

```
ID  Year    CHAR1   n_CHAR1
A   2016    0       3   
A   2017    5       3
A   2018    2       3
A   2019            3
B   2016    1       2
B   2017            2
B   2018            2
B   2019    1       2
```

And so on for all characteristics. I would insert the "n_CHAR" columns to the original dataframe.

It doesn't need to be tidy.
Thanks!

Comment: Your example only has one column where you need this done, but you describe it as a problem that might need to happen for multiple columns. You also say you want to count observations by ID and year, but then show and describe the count by ID only. Can you clarify / expand the example to better show what you want?

Comment: @camille can you even please explain how n_char is 3 for the first row?

Comment: @AAA `n_CHAR1` is supposed to be the count of non-missing entries in `CHAR1` for each `ID`. Since `ID=A` has four rows, and there are 3 non-missing entries, the count of 3 gets repeated four times in `n_CHAR1`. Same for `B` and so on..

Comment: @AAA there are 3 rows for which ID A has a non-blank CHAR1, so n_CHAR1 = 3, and 2 rows for which ID B has a non-blank CHAR1

Comment: @camille thank you!!!

Comment: @camille you are correct, I wasn't clear enough. I would want to count by ID and some other category, say Season (Winter/Summer). If my ID is in multiple years, I would sum those in winter only with those in winter and those in summer only with those in summer. Regarding the CHAR column, there would be many of them in my dataframe; in the example I used just one for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
transform(final_database, n_CHAR1 = ave(CHAR1, ID, FUN = function(x) sum(x != "")))
```

If the blank rows are actually `NA`, then just replace `sum(x != "")` with `sum(!is.na(x))`.

*Edit*:

If you'd need multiple `n` columns for multiple `NCHAR` columns, you could do:

```
library(dplyr)

final_database %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("CHAR")),
            list(n = ~ sum(. != "")))
```

This example assumes that all the relevant `NCHAR` columns start with the string `NCHAR` (e.g. `NCHAR1`, `NCHAR2`, `NCHAR3`, etc.).

If the columns you're referring to are *3rd to last*, then you can do:

```
library(dplyr)

finalDatabase <- final_database %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(3:ncol(.)), # If you don't have many other vars except NCHAR, you can also do vars(-ID, -Year) as suggested by @camille
            list(n = ~ sum(. != ""))) %>%
  select(ID, Year, ends_with("_n"))
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like the solution. But what if I don't actually know the name of my CHAR columns? I mean, they are many and have varied names.

Comment: Do they have a fixed place? For example, if you'd like to refer to all columns between 3rd and 100th, you would replace `vars(starts_with("CHAR"))` with `vars(3:100)`. Otherwise you'd need to find a common denominator, something to work with.

Comment: Sort of. They are 3rd until last, and the last one could be 50th or 60th or whatever.

Comment: See the additional option at the end of my post now, that should work

Comment: That is perfect. One last question: what if I want to write that result in another dataframe with only my ID, Year and the new calculated (CHAR_n) column but without the CHAR column, how would I proceed?

Comment: I've added this option, check the additional `select` statement. This would save only the desired columns in a new dataframe called `finalDatabase`.

Comment: If you don't know which columns it *is*, but do know which columns it *isn't*, you can also use `vars(-ID, -Year)`

Comment: Thanks @camille, indeed that's also an option.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, n_CHAR1 := sum(CHAR1 != ""), by = "ID"]
```

**Output:**

```
   ID Year CHAR1 n_CHAR1
1:  A 2016     0       3
2:  A 2017     5       3
3:  A 2018     2       3
4:  A 2019             3
5:  B 2016     1       2
6:  B 2017             2
7:  B 2018             2
8:  B 2019     1       2
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
    Year = c(2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 
    2019L), CHAR1 = c("0", "5", "2", "", "1", "", "", "1")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```